# Permuting the cost function in Keras

Tags: r, keras, loss-function

Currently I try to predict the locations of certain objects in an image in Keras R. I'm only interested in the centers of the object so I try to predict the center coordinates (x_center, y_center) in the image. I assume that there is a maximum of two of these objects in my image. My target of learning is therefore the vector:

```
label = c(x_center_1, y_center_1, x_center_2, y_center_2)
```

The common loss function "mean_squared_error" does not work since the first two and last two can be permuted without changing a thing.

The los that I'm looking for is

```
min( rmse(output, c(x_center_1, y_center_1, x_center_2, y_center_2)),  rmse(output, c( x_center_2, y_center_2, x_center_1, y_center_1))
```

where rmse is the root mean squared error function and output is the output of my model.

The way I thought I needed to implement a custom mad loss was by defining a loss function LOSS and just plugging it in like this

```
compile(model, loss=LOSS, optimizer=opt, metrics = "accuracy")
```

For this to work I need to write the following functions using Keras backend functions

```
rmse = function(v1,v2){
sqrt(sum(  (v1- v2)^2 )/ length(v1) )
}

LOSS = function(label, output){
min( rmse(output,  label  ),  rmse(output, label[c(3,4,1,2)])  )
}
```

I especially get stuck when I try to get the permutation  label[c(3,4,1,2)]) to work.

Am I approaching this problem in the right way? How can I permute a vector in the Keras backend?

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit permute function but to that end there is `gather(reference, indices)` which will retrieve "the elements of indices `indices` in the tensor `reference`". So you can use it for `K.gather(label, [3,4,1,2])` to get the vector you want, [doc](https://keras.io/backend/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I made my loss function as follows

```
rmse = function(v1,v2){
return(  k_sum(  k_square( layer_subtract( list(v1, v2) )) )  )
}

loss = function(label, output){
output_1 =  output[,1:2]
output_2 =  output[,3:4]
output_new = k_concatenate( list(output_2, output_1))
return(k_minimum( rmse(output,  label  ),  rmse(output_new,  label )  ))
}
```

This seems to work fine. broadcasting and concatenating the tensors seems to work better than gathering them.